# NY & Federal Quarterly tax payments for someone with Fulltime job and a side gig?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, new-york

In 2020 I want to start paying estimated quarterly taxes but I am not sure exactly how to calculate the amounts.

If I make X$ yearly income from my full time job have maximum withholding. I also expect to make additional $Y a year from my side gig as an IT consultant where I do not have much deductions.

Is it enough to pay (35% of Y$/4) of my additional income or do I have to sum up the entire income and then figure out quarterly payment? do I have to do the same thing for federal quarterly tax payment and State tax payments?
Do you think this situation is complicated to need an accountant?

Comment: We have a progressive income tax system. It is impossible to estimate how much tax you might have to pay without knowing what your income is.

Comment: I could update the question with the numbers but I would like to know how to calculate it using variables. I'm sure formulas exist, no?

Comment: Of course. Look at form 1040-ES and the NY state equivalent.  The 2020 1040-ES is not yet available, but the 2019 revision will be pretty much the same except for the tax brackets.

Comment: Thanks .. I did look at it but  I will study it now.. the only issue that the form does not describe  (or I can't figure out) is my situation where I have a W2 and 1099-Misc ( full time income + additional freelance income )

Comment: @smarty, your W2 and 1099 income is all included on line 1a of the worksheet "expected income and profits", which you would essentially copy from line 8b "adjusted gross income" of a rough 2020 1040 you would fill out.

Comment: Instead of paying estimated taxes, another option would be to update your W-4 at your full-time job to withhold extra.

Comment: What @user4556274 said is incorrect. On the Self Employment Tax Worksheet, line 1a, you put only your self-employment income. You put your regular wages on line 6. On the Estimated Tax Worksheet, line 1, you include both your W2 income and your self-employment income, less the amount on line 11 of the Self-Employment Tax Worksheet. The amount from line 10 of the Self-Employment Tax Worksheet goes on line 9 of the Estimated Tax Worksheet. This instructions are on the worksheets and instructions. (I'm looking at the 2019 instructions. The 2020 instructions are probably the same, but may not be.)

Comment: @prl thank you, I see that 2020 instructions are released. I started doing my 2019 taxes and it looks like I am expected to owe ~20K in federal taxes because of my additional income. If I don't expect my income to change in 2020, should I just pay $(20/4 = 5) for quarterly payments? or I must fill in the forms and do more appropriate calculation?

Comment: The IRS doesn't care whether you fill in the worksheets or not; it only cares that you pay the right amount. If you think your estimate is within 10% of what your actual taxes will be this year, then it is a reasonable estimate. The interest rate for underpayment is actually fairly reasonable (currently 5%), and it is only applied to the amount of underpayment, so it's not too big a deal to be off somewhat.